# Relatively new WD Red Pro yielding ATA status: 41 (DRDY ERR), error: 40 (UNC ) on FreeBSD 12.2

Tags: hard-drive, freebsd, zfs, sata, smart

I am running a **TrueNAS** server based on **FreeBSD 12.2**. I migrated the storage to **10 TB WD Red Pro**. They're running for 42 days now.

Out of the sudden, during a ZFS scrub, one of the disks yielded 5 errors. All of them more or less read:

```
(ada2:ahcich14:0:0:0): READ_FPDMA_QUEUED. ACB: 60 b8 08 3a 0f 40 f8 01 00 07 00 00
(ada2:ahcich14:0:0:0): CAM status: ATA Status Error
(ada2:ahcich14:0:0:0): ATA status: 41 (DRDY ERR), error: 40 (UNC )
(ada2:ahcich14:0:0:0): RES: 41 40 90 3b 0f 40 f8 01 00 30 06
(ada2:ahcich14:0:0:0): Retrying command, 3 more tries remain
```

I ran an **extended SMART test** after the incident, but it yielded no errors (except those that were recorded), especially no relocated sectors or such:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE-p2 amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD102KFBX-68M95N0
Serial Number:    [deleted]
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 0b0cd3041
Firmware Version: 83.00A83
User Capacity:    10,000,831,348,736 bytes [10.0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    [deleted]
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   87) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (1108) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0004   132   132   054    Old_age   Offline      -       96
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   100   100   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000a   100   100   067    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0004   128   128   020    Old_age   Offline      -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1077
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0012   100   100   060    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       215
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       215
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   142   142   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (Min/Max 25/67)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 5
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 5 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1050 hours (43 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 b8 10 08 3a 0f 40 08  15d+21:45:25.729  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 38 b8 60 0f 40 08  15d+21:45:18.777  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 30 f8 58 0f 40 08  15d+21:45:18.775  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 28 40 51 0f 40 08  15d+21:45:18.775  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 20 80 49 0f 40 08  15d+21:45:15.608  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 4 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1050 hours (43 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 b8 28 10 d8 0e 40 08  15d+21:45:10.298  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 40 48 ef 0e 40 08  15d+21:45:03.370  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 38 88 e7 0e 40 08  15d+21:45:03.178  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 30 d0 df 0e 40 08  15d+21:45:00.444  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 20 f0 d3 0e 40 08  15d+21:45:00.286  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 3 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1050 hours (43 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 b8 00 90 81 23 40 08  15d+21:41:08.578  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 10 08 91 23 40 08  15d+21:41:08.336  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 08 48 89 23 40 08  15d+21:41:01.627  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 f8 d0 79 23 40 08  15d+21:40:57.546  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 f0 18 72 23 40 08  15d+21:40:56.899  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1050 hours (43 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 b8 18 f0 d5 17 40 08  15d+21:34:13.263  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 50 10 0c 18 40 08  15d+21:34:06.288  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 48 58 04 18 40 08  15d+21:34:06.288  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 40 98 fc 17 40 08  15d+21:34:06.288  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 38 e0 f4 17 40 08  15d+21:34:06.288  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1050 hours (43 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 b8 50 28 8b 17 40 08  15d+21:33:33.959  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b8 48 70 83 17 40 08  15d+21:33:16.648  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 40 e8 82 17 40 08  15d+21:33:16.647  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 40 08  15d+21:33:16.640  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  61 08 30 f0 fd 3f 40 08  15d+21:33:16.638  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1072         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1023         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       946         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       855         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       687         -
# 6  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       610         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       519         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       279         -
# 9  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       202         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       111         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        11         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

In the first place I though I might have bought a defective disk. I would have expected SMART to fail assessment. However, this is not the case. I don't think it's a defective PSU, because it's not even one year old. Also, it's a 550 Watts PSU and the machine consumes about 100 Watts. I don't think it's a defective cable, either, because I was running other disks for almost a year without problems. Also, with these other discs I actually *had* a defective cable, which I replaced, and the observations were different.

I am considering to RMA the drive, although I am not sure if it qualifies for an RMA. What do you think? May that be a transient error? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Anything at all in the error log is RMA worthy.

Comment: Thank you so far, Michael. I was concerned because the drive passs the assessment and also because the temperature seems to have exceeded the maximum operating temperature by 2 degrees once during resivering in the first place. The mean temperatures are ok and I can see that using collectd. However, maybe it's enough for WD to refuse the RMA. ‍♂️

Comment: I've sent many drives back to WD (and all the other manufacturers). They are very good at taking drives back. I can't recall ever having one refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your replies. Based on what you said I decided to RMA the drive to Western Digital. The drive has already been replaced.

Answer (score 2):

`UNC` means **UNC**orrectable errors, which are often due to medium error (ie: a physical sector gone bad). However, you SMART log shows that the error happened at LBA 0x0. While theoretically possible, it seems very strange to me that you *precisely* hit a read error at that address. This seems confirmed by the reported SMART pending sectors (0), but I saw many disks not updating that field correctly.

Can you read LBA 0 at all? Please report what happens when executing the following command:

`dd if=<your_disk> of=/dev/null bs=512 count=1 iflag=direct`

If you can successfully read LBA, it is probable that you have a cabling issue or that the electronic of your HDD is failing/unstable.

Comment: Hmm. This does seem to have the unique smell of drive electronics. I wouldn't expect the drive to log this sort of error if the data cable was having a problem.

Comment: The dd command just worked as expected. No errors whatsoever. Also, I already had cabling issues a year ago and they occurred way more often until I swapped the cable and they have only been logged to the console as CRC errors. They have never been recorded in the SMART logs. But I was also confused by this very LBA. Meanwhile I did a second scrub which ran for some hours stressing the discs without any issue.